# how to swap&recolonize between words a in a string

Tags: c#-2.0

an h.w c# question:
I have a string with 4 words (for instance: `string = "Joe walking every day";`
the task is to recognize the 3rd word (of any string...) and swap it with the first one
so my output string will be "every walking Joe day"

I was thinking to use for? if? indexer? a direction will be as much good as the full answer

Code from comment:

```
int counter = 0;
string lyrics = "Joe walking every day";
Console.WriteLine(lyrics[3]);
for (int i = 0; i < lyrics.Length; i++) {
    if (lyrics[i] ==' ') {
        if (counter==2) {
            //must be the start of 3rd word
            if (counter==3) {
                //must be the end of 3rd word
            }
        }
    }
} //this is as far I reached
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you post your code?

Comment: int counter = 0;
            string lyrics = "Joe walking every day"          for (int i = 0; i < lyrics.Length; i++)
          {
              if (lyrics[i] ==' ')
              {
                  if (counter==2)
                  {
                      //must be the start of 3rd word
                      if (counter==3)
                      {
                          //must be the end of 3rd word
                      }
                  }
              }
        }  //this is  as far I reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
string lyrics = "Joe walking every day";
String[] words = lyrics.Split(" ");
string firstWord = words[0];
string thirdWord = words[2];
words[0] = thirdWord;
words[2] = firstWord;
string swapped = string.Join(" ",words);
Console.WriteLine(swapped);
```

Comment: @YogevStrauber if it worked for you then you can mark the answer as accepted so others will know the solution you found.

Comment: Hey peter, Sorry Im kinda new arround, how now I do that?

Comment: @YogevStrauber Is there a check box or something on the answer? Lol, I've never asked a question so I'm not sure!

Comment: haha I as noob as it get, no worry I'll catch up real quick, marked the answer in green V, Hope it does the work. Let me know if not, u should stick arround, more question like this will come up !